# Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{n-k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, taylor-expansion

I am reading a paper which casually assumes the asymptotic $\sqrt{n-k} \simeq \sqrt{n}-\frac{k}{2\sqrt{n}}$. This expression is what Wolfram calls Taylor expansion at infinity and from what I understand we work with $\sqrt{x-k}=\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{1-k/x}$ and then we proceed on doing the Taylor expansion. My problem is that we also cannot do Taylor expansion near zero because said function is not differentiable there.
Another point is: do the Taylor expansion near point $1$ for $\sqrt{x}$ so that
$$\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-k/x} = \sqrt{x} - \frac{k}{2\sqrt{x}} - \frac{k^2}{8x^{3/2}}\frac{1}{\xi^{3/2}},$$ where $\xi$ as in Legendre residual form (between $1-k/x$ and $1$). We can then deduce that $\sqrt{n-k}\leq \sqrt{n}-k/2\sqrt{n},$ but what about the lower bound? Is there a way to fix an inequality relating the remainder and the second term of the above expansion? 
**My real question**, is how to use the aforementioned fact in order to get a result of the form $$\sqrt{x-1/2}\geq \sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac{4}{x}\right).$$ The first two terms of $\sqrt{x-1/2}$ in the above expansion should be $\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{x}},$ so the remainder term should be $\geq -\frac{15}{4\sqrt{x}}$ or something.

Comment: You want to show $\sqrt{x-\frac12}\ge\sqrt x(1-\frac4x)$?  The left side must be positive, but for $x<4$, the right side is negative.  Square both sides, and you'll see the left side is greater than the right side for $x>\frac{32}{15}$.  QED

Comment: When I wrote “positive”, I meant “non-negative”

Comment: Which paper are you reading?

Comment: @Jack Both [Ramirez, et al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0607331.pdf) in chapter $6$ and [Edelman, Sutton](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0607038.pdf) (I believe in ch. 4) use the $\sqrt{n-k}$ estimate, while the explanation via Taylor can "almost surely" be inferred from [Small Deviations for Beta Ensembles (Ledoux, Rider)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejp/1464819826) (eq 2.8, 2.9)

Comment: So you "real" question is showing $\sqrt{n-k} \simeq \sqrt{n}-\frac{k}{2\sqrt{n}}$ for $k=1/4$, isn't it? That is, for *large enough* $n$, $$C_1\sqrt{n-k} \leq \sqrt{n}-\frac{k}{2\sqrt{n}}\leq C_2 \sqrt{n-k} $$ for some constants $C_1,C_2$.

Comment: "Asymptotic" behavior does *not* require $f(x)\geq g(x)$ for *all* $x$ in the "domain".

Comment: That's how I was interpreting it at first, but in the first and third cited paper they seem to ignore the constants so I started searching for something "tighter". My goal is to show the results from ch. 6 of the first reference. So I will have to apply  my "real" question for $x=\beta(n-k)$, and then apply an estimate of the type you proposed (or a modification of the Taylor method perhaps) for the estimate of $\sqrt{n-k}$.

Comment: @separableninja: which result in ch.6 of Ramirez-et-al that is relevant to the question here? Lemma 6.3?

Comment: @Jack yes that would be the case.

Comment: @separableninja: Then I think what you need not quite the "asymptotic" behavior as claimed in the post. You want instead two inequalities: $\sqrt{r}(1-4/r)\leq E_{\chi_r}$ and $E_{\chi_r}\leq\sqrt{r}$, where $\chi_r$ is the random variable with [Chi distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution). The proof of the second one is given in Ledoux-Rider as you cited.

Comment: @Jack: these estimates can be deduced- no problem. the application of this lower bound in order to upper bound $\sqrt{n}-\beta^{-1/2}E\chi$ by $2kn^{-1/2}$ is where issues arise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show that $\sqrt{x-1/2}\geq \sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac{4}{x}\right),$

the following argument is simpler than bounding Taylor series terms:

(a)  for $\frac12\le x<4$:   $\sqrt{x-1/2}\geq0\gt \sqrt{x}\left(1-\frac{4}{x}\right);$

(b) for $x>\frac{32}{15}, \frac{15}2>\frac{16}x,$ so $x-\frac12>x-8+\frac{16}x=x(1-\frac4x)^2, $ so $\sqrt{x-1/2}>\sqrt x(1-\frac4x);$

so we have shown $\sqrt{x-1/2}>\sqrt x\left(1-\frac4x\right)$ for all $x$ where $\sqrt{x-1/2}$ is defined.

Comment: That is indeed true. However, I still need to understand a way to do it via the Taylor expansion method, as I also want to apply it to $\sqrt{n-k}$. Thanks for your time.